# PHP regex escape character error: "preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing )"

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

**Disclaimer**

For the purposes of an easy to read example - I am assigning the text that should match to the variable `$data`. In reality this text is within a large text document that is read via `file_get_contents()`.

**Explanation of Problem as I understand it so far**

I am getting the error: `Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 61` - While I understand that this is likely due to an escape character being incorrect in my regex (deduced from similar posts on stack overflow), I can't seem to spot my mistake. Could someone please point out where the mistake I have made is that is causing the error above?

**My Code**

```
$data = "dbparts = array('test', 'test', 'test', 'test');";
$pattern = "/dbparts = array\('([^']*)', '([^']*)', '([^']*)', '([^']*'\);/";
preg_match($pattern, $data, $results);
```

Comment: you have one more **(** than **)**

Comment: Or you're really just missing a `)` after your last placeholder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One ")" needs to be added-

```
/dbparts = array\('([^']*)', '([^']*)', '([^']*)', '([^']*)'\);/
                                                          ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
$pattern = "/dbparts = array\('([^']*)', '([^']*)', '([^']*)', '([^']*)'\);/";
```

I added a ) before the last '.